# UIImageView layer won't transform more than once

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opencv, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView that I want to transform inside a callback (specifically: using OpenCV processImage). Inside the callback I calculate an angle at which it should be transformed and set the transform to that angle. It works only the first time, but won't update (I'm logging the angle and have verified that it changes).

However, If I attach a button to the same code I can apply the transform multiple times with no problems. I can also mix the two actions (applying rotate inside the processImage callback and applying rotate on button tap) but rotation only takes affect on the button tap.

Is there some kind of redraw method I'm missing to tell the UIImageView to redraw itself that gets called automatically on button tap?

This `actionRotate` works fine and applies the rotation every time I tap the button.

```
- (IBAction)actionRotate:(id)sender {
    if (!self.angle) {
        self.angle = 0.5f;
    } else {
        self.angle += 0.1f;
    }

    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
    self.image.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, self.angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    self.image.layer.zPosition = 1000;

    NSLog(@"actionRotate angle: %f", self.angle);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // init camera
    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:self.output];
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    // 1 fps to slow down log output for debugging
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 1;
    self.output.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 480);
    [self.videoCamera start];
}
```

This `processImage` does not work. The angle gets incremented correctly, but the transform doesn't get applied. Even if I call `[self actionRotate:nil]` to be absolutely sure it's the same code running.

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{
    if (!self.angle) {
        self.angle = 0.5f;
    } else {
        self.angle += 0.1f;
    }

    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
    self.image.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, self.angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    self.image.layer.zPosition = 1000;

    NSLog(@"processImage angle: %f", self.angle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that it wasn't running in the main queue, so had to change the code doing the transform in `processImage`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.deviation.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, self.angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    self.deviation.layer.zPosition = 1000;
});
```